# Non linear least squares with non vertical residuals

Tags: regression, least-squares, nonlinear-regression

*Disclaimer: my scholar math level is quite basic, and english is not my native language, so please forgive me for the words I will use.*

I have a point cloud (~50000 points) and I would like to fit a specific function to this point cloud:

$$
y = a \cdot ln\left(\frac{1 - (1 - b)e^{\frac{x}{c}}}{b}\right)
$$

However, my point cloud is such that measurements errors (residuals?) are not vertical, but always "with the same slope in regards to the Y axis".

It looks a bit like the orthogonal least squares problem:

[image: Orthogonal least squares]

except:

1. The function I need to fit is non linear.
2. The residuals won't always be orthogonal to the curve, but will always have the same "slope" (45°) in regards to the X and Y axis.

It *feels* like all I have to do is modify the residuals function I pass to  [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html), but I cannot seem to find how.

Right now, I am doing:

```
def my_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.log((1 - (1 - b) * np.exp(x / c)) / b)

def residual(p, x, y):
    return y - my_func(x, *p)

result = optimize.least_squares(
    residual,
    args=(x, y),  # x, y = my point cloud
)
```

Is there a simple way to modify the `residual` function such that the errors to minimize are not "vertical"? Do I need to use orthogonal least squares here?